# Average Mean time colume Column h:MM:SS CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

| Sessions | Bounce Rate | Pages / Session | AVD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 314636 | 34.75% | 2.02 | 0:04:25 |
| 0 | 0.00% | 0 | 0:00:00 |
| 25402 | 56.48% | 1.69 | 0:04:24 |
| 595 | 49.58% | 2.25 | 0:02:26 |
| 13055 | 18.47% | 3.56 | 0:04:25 |
| 2964 | 21.32% | 3.7 | 0:02:26 |

Hi there! the table above is a snippet of the CSV to help you get an idea of data. I want to a general method to find the mean/average of the AVD column.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('ga.csv')
df['avd']=pd.to_datetime(df['avd'], format='H:MM:SS')
print(df['avd'].mean())
```

but before the print statement i get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '0:04:25' does not match format 'H:MM:SS' (match)
```

If I add errors='ignore' then i get this error form the print statement:

```
Could not convert 0:04:250:00:000:04:240:02:260:04:250:02:260:06:090:00:000....(and so on)...to numeric.
```

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: what does `AVD` represent? to me, it looks like a duration (see @RobRaymond's answer...)

Comment: Hi @MrFuppes! Those are indeed duration values however, im looking for a more generalized solution.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `timedelta`, not `datetime` as it's just a time.  Below works

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Sessions    Bounce Rate Pages / Session AVD
314636  34.75%  2.02    0:04:25
0   0.00%   0   0:00:00
25402   56.48%  1.69    0:04:24
595 49.58%  2.25    0:02:26
13055   18.47%  3.56    0:04:25
2964    21.32%  3.7 0:02:26
"""), sep="\t")


df["AVD"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["AVD"])
df["AVD"].mean()
```

Comment: Ok great! And i do see that it works. My issue with your solution is that it seems it would require that i copy/paste the dataframe as a string.

The problem is that im trying to automate a process and would need to access a specific column in the dataframe that lists time values and find the mean, without much user input. Is there way to do that?

Comment: the reason SO requests that you post your data as text is so it is reproducible - I received the data as text on this web page and turned it into a DF.  If I delete how I got ur data into a DF solution still stays the same :-). Nowhere does the approach define how you get data into a DF ....  just it needs to be a timedelta